# DynamoDB trigger event based on item counter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have a DynamoDB table which has an attribute counter, which will be decremented asynchronously by multiple lambda based on an event. I want to trigger another event when the counter becomes zero. How can I achieve this ? I am using the DynamoDB enhanced Client (Java SDK 2).

I tried using the DynamoDBVersionAttribute but it is quite tricky to maintain it, since the counter is getting updated asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly it is important to understand that by default DynamoDB uses a [eventually consistent read model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html) which will not function well if you're expecting your counter to be [atomic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters).

> An atomic counter would not be appropriate where overcounting or undercounting can't be tolerated (for example, in a banking application). In this case, it is safer to use a conditional update instead of an atomic counter.

Instead take a look at [conditional updates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate).

Rather than trying to get the value on update instead take a look at using [DynamoDB streams](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/) to react after the write has been performed.

By handling the even this way it will allow you to trigger and process events based on conditions such as for your case the counter reaching 0.

The stream can be read by another application or integrate with other services such as [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) to [process the events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!! Does dynamodb sdk 2 supports conditional writes?

Comment: Yes, this documentation gives details of how it can be used: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPIItemCRUD.html#PutDocumentAPIJava

Comment: Thanks.. This was very helpful !! 
Do you have any idea how to update specific fields using UpdateItemEnhancedRequest?